# Why do these Japanese characters have different top values?

Tags: html, css, unicode, translation

I'm trying to figure out why the div with "コンシェルジュ" has a different top than the divs that contain "警備" and "洗濯".  You'll have to actually run the code snippet to see what I mean but on the first row the first row has a top 3 pixels above the second and third div on that row... I'm at a loss for why.  Is this a language thing?  How do I make them have the same top, in a natural sense?  I don't want to use Javascript to force the tops to be the same, because I'm using the top values already to determine what row a content div is in, so that could become circular.

There is an English version of this where only difference is the content's verbiage and in English (and Mandarin and Korean) and I do not have this problem.  It seems to be something unique to Japanese lettering, is there something I have to account for with Japanese?

```css
.DemoQuest {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verlag, Arial;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

.DemoQuest .Span {
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ResponseSet {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.DemoResp {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .5%;
    padding-bottom: .5%;
    width: 32%;
}

.ResponseText {
    display: none;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

.DemoResp .Wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: black;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.DemoQuest .DemoResp .Selector .Wrapper {
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div id="d2929b66837440708d3db2ed658ca0c6" class="DemoQuest">
  <div class="Span">以下、ホテル内でご利用いただいたサービスをお選び下さい</div>
  <div class="ResponseSet Below">
   <div id="96e3902628074785a3065df70c644566" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_96e3902628074785a3065df70c644566" name="cb_96e3902628074785a3065df70c644566" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"><div class="ResponseContent">コンシェルジュ</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">コンシェルジュ</span>
   </div>
   <div id="8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6" name="cb_8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6"><div class="ResponseContent">警備</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">警備</span>
   </div>
   <div id="de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98" name="cb_de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98"><div class="ResponseContent">洗濯</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">洗濯</span>
   </div>
   <div id="346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866" name="cb_346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866" value="1" ><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866"><div class="ResponseContent" style="height: 52px; top: 13px;">お土産屋</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">お土産屋</span>
   </div>
   <div id="6750438a3faf49a8afbbca7c23289a42" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_6750438a3faf49a8afbbca7c23289a42" name="cb_6750438a3faf49a8afbbca7c23289a42" value="1" ><div id="123" class="Wrapper"><div class="ResponseContent">バンニャンツリースパ</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">バンニャンツリースパ</span>
   </div>
   <div id="fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b" name="cb_fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b"><div class="ResponseContent">フィットネスセンター</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">フィットネスセンター</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: In case anyone runs into this issue and thinks it is a Kana v Kanji issue, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As me understand, you have to add `vertical-align: top` to your `.DemoResp` css to fix this problem.

```
.DemoResp {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .5%;
    padding-bottom: .5%;
    width: 32%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This works, but do you know why I have to do this for Japanese when other languages I don't have to?

Comment: May be this is the font issue which you are using for Japanese, may be I am wrong. But if you are using `display: inline-block` then you have to use `vertical-align` property of css to align the inline elements symmetrically.

Comment: Thanks again, this was exactly what was wrong.  It has to be something with the font I'm using.  I guess Verlag's Japanese is a little weird.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.DemoQuest {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Verlag, Arial;
    color: white;
    background: black;
}

.DemoQuest .Span {
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ResponseSet {
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.DemoResp {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: .5%;
    padding-bottom: .5%;
    width: 32%;
}

.ResponseText {
    display: none;
}

input {
    display: none;
}

.DemoResp .Wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: black;
    height: 30px; /* <-- this is what i have add*/
    padding: 8px 8px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 15px;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.DemoQuest .DemoResp .Selector .Wrapper {
    display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div id="d2929b66837440708d3db2ed658ca0c6" class="DemoQuest">
  <div class="Span">以下、ホテル内でご利用いただいたサービスをお選び下さい</div>
  <div class="ResponseSet Below">
   <div id="96e3902628074785a3065df70c644566" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_96e3902628074785a3065df70c644566" name="cb_96e3902628074785a3065df70c644566" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"><div class="ResponseContent">コンシェルジュ</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">コンシェルジュ</span>
   </div>
   <div id="8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6" name="cb_8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_8d69877355cd4f05a4db3539c2f67fd6"><div class="ResponseContent">警備</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">警備</span>
   </div>
   <div id="de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98" name="cb_de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_de5a147b403f43568d44169142ae4a98"><div class="ResponseContent">洗濯</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">洗濯</span>
   </div>
   <div id="346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866" name="cb_346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866" value="1" ><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_346cb8895aa34c4ebf879814f197e866"><div class="ResponseContent" style="height: 52px; top: 13px;">お土産屋</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">お土産屋</span>
   </div>
   <div id="6750438a3faf49a8afbbca7c23289a42" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_6750438a3faf49a8afbbca7c23289a42" name="cb_6750438a3faf49a8afbbca7c23289a42" value="1" ><div id="123" class="Wrapper"><div class="ResponseContent">バンニャンツリースパ</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">バンニャンツリースパ</span>
   </div>
   <div id="fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b" class="DemoResp">
    <span class="Selector"><input type="checkbox" id="cb_fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b" name="cb_fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b" value="1"><div id="123" class="Wrapper"  for="cb_fd64fa6d551848d18943f7210633045b"><div class="ResponseContent">フィットネスセンター</div></div></span>
    <span class="ResponseText">フィットネスセンター</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```